# Is $A \implies \neg A$ a valid contradiction?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, proof-writing

Say I want to prove that a proposition $A$ is false. I do a *proof by contradiction* where I assume $A$ is true and show that $\neg A$ follows. Is this a valid contradiction?

I think that this contradicts the Law of Excluded middle, because $A$ and $\neg A$ are true at the same time. So $A$ can't be true in the same universe as where the law of excluded middle holds, and because law of excluded middle is true, A must not be true.

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that is a valid use of contradiction

Comment: Indeed, $A\implies\lnot A$ is logically equivalent to $\lnot A$ (as a truth table shows, as well as the OP's argument).

Comment: $A\implies \lnot A$ and $A\implies A$ means $A\implies (A\land \lnot A)$

Comment: See my comment following the answer of Mark Saving.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a valid proof technique. You begin by assuming $A$. You then demonstrate $\neg A$. Since we have both $A$ and $\neg A$, we have a contradiction. Thus, we conclude $\neg A$.

However, this is *not* a proof by contradiction. Proof by contradiction is a technique wherein one proves $P$ by assuming $\neg P$ and deriving a contradiction. This is proof of negation - we are proving $\neg A$ by assuming $A$ and deriving a contradiction.

Comment: In fact, it **is** a proof by contradiction.  You assume that the assertion is false, namely that $\neg A$ is false.  This is equivalent to assuming that $A$ is true.  Then, you prove that $\neg A$ is true.  Since you can't have $A$ and $\neg A$ both true, you have a contradiction.  Therefore, the assumption that $\neg A$ is false has *led to a contradiction*.

Comment: “You assume that the assertion is false, namely that $\neg A$ is false. This is equivalent to assuming that $A$ is true.” You have just given me a separate proof which begins by saying “Assume $\neg \neg A$“, instead of beginning by saying “Assume $A$”. The proof OP gave does not mention assuming $\neg \neg A$. But you are correct that if you wish to make the proof needlessly more complex, you can incorporate proof by contradiction. The distinction between proof of negation and proof by contradiction is a meaningful one, especially when one deals with constructive logic.